# How to insert image into Access database using Classic ASP

Tags: database, ms-access, asp-classic

I am trying to use my webcam to take a picture and save it into an Access database with other information like first name, surname etc.

I have so far created a page that is able to insert the other details into the database. I now don't know how to go about with the image.

For now, I need help on how to capture the image and save into Access table.

Comment: Don’t use Access, what is stopping you using SQL Server Express Edition?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could handle this would be to instead of inserting the image, you could store it in a relevant folder with the database'images', then instead insert the path to the image.

However if you **need** to have it in the db, you could use [attachments to table records](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/attach-files-and-graphics-to-the-records-in-your-database-d40a09ad-a753-4a14-9161-7f15baad6dbd). Ive never done this, but from a glance it looks limited. As MS access databases max out at 2GB.

Comment: Thank you pants. Can you please help me with the line of code to achieve your recommendation? That is to insert the image into a folder and the link in the MS Access DB.

Comment: @YayraKoku I have no code to base a suggestion off of. I offered up multiple recommendations and see no attempts of trying to implement either.